# Replacing all values of the first row with a "0"

Tags: notepad++

I have measured data:

```
Date;Time;Status;Alarm;Eingang;;T100[s];H2 [ppm];H2raw [ppm]
1.1.13;02:02;Comment;Comment;Comment; Value;Value;Value;
1.1.13;02:03;Comment;Comment;Comment; Value;Value;Value;
1.1.13;02:04;Comment;Comment;Comment; Value;Value;Value;
1.1.13;02:05;Comment;Comment;Comment; Value;Value;Value;
```

I would like to replace all values of the second and last row with a "0".

Could anyone give me a tip?

Comment: the last *column* you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You can let `awk` do that for you

```
cat datafile | awk -F";" '{print $1";0;"$3";"$4";"$5";"$6";0;"$8";"}'
```

There are also other possibilities to do that but I find `awk` is the easiest here.

Comment: i guess this is part of the macro i need to write. im trying to figure out how to write a macro.